# Rows.Count fails to count rows if RemoveDuplicates doesn't find duplicates

Tags: c#, excel, duplicates

On a report I'm working on, after the SQL dumps the data into a new excel sheet I have to check for duplicate records by the Transaction Number column, column AE(31)

Here is part of the code that counts the rows used, defines the range, removes the duplicates and after re-counts and defines a new range for the next function.

```
//Removed duplicate transactions
int trnsCount = JobDataSheet.Rows.Count;
trnsCount = JobDataSheet.Cells[trnsCount, 1].End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;
Excel.Range transRng = JobDataSheet.get_Range("A1:AE" + trnsCount);
transRng.RemoveDuplicates(31);

//Check if report has been run for 1 or multiple Jobs
int MyCount = JobDataSheet.Rows.Count;
MyCount = JobDataSheet.Cells[trnsCount, 1].End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;
```

Here is where things get odd.

The MyCount variable **fails** to find the last row used **if** the RemoveDuplicate function did **not** find any duplicates.

Case an point:
Report 10701 has a total of 1415 rows (82 of which are duplicates) the RemoveDuplicate kicks in an removes them leaving 1333. For this report, trnsCount when watched correctly calculates 1415 rows and MyCount correctly calculates 1333 rows after the duplicates have been removed.

Report 14506 has a total of 12 rows (0 duplicates) so the RemoveDuplicate removes no rows from this report. For this report, trnsCount when watched correctly calculates 12 rows but MyCount only calculates 1 row.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay attention on your variable `trnsCount`:

```
// trnsCount = Rows.Count
int trnsCount = JobDataSheet.Rows.Count;
// trnsCount = 12
trnsCount = JobDataSheet.Cells[trnsCount, 1].End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;
```

Then, after removing duplicates, you're using `trnsCount` (which is equal to `12`) to get last row:

```
MyCount = JobDataSheet.Cells[trnsCount, 1].End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;
```

and obviously this is incorrect, since you should use `Rows.Count` instead `12`.

So, just change above line to:

```
MyCount = JobDataSheet.Cells[MyCount , 1].End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;
```